# deserialize json string cant find whats wrong with my class

Tags: json, deserialization

i try to deserialize this json string

```
{"errors":null,"value":{
    "APIVersion":"0.0.1",
    "resturantName":"Imperial Lanes",
    "serverVersion":"4.3.133",
    "user{
        "authorities":null,
        "barCode":11,
        "firstname":"Admin",
        "identifier":1,
        "lastname":"-"
         }
     }
 }
```

using

```
Result<LoginResponse> loginResponse = 
    jsonSerialiser.Deserialize<Result<LoginResponse>>(Response);
```

where Response is my json string,
but i get error: No parameterless constructor defined for type of...

my classes looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public class Result<T>
{
    public Result(T value, ErrorMessage errors)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public T value { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ErrorMessage errors { get; private set; }
}

public class LoginResponse
{
    public string serverVersion;
    public string APIVersion; // "0.0.1"
    public string resturantName;
    public User user = new User();
}

public class User
{
    public long identifier;
    public long barCode;
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
    public List<string> authorities;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide parameterless constructor as error states

Comment: your json is invalid. Check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i get that json string from my wcf webservice. whats wrong with it?

Comment: what is parameterless constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx
json.net with the same class and same jsonstring and it worked perfectly.